# M2 Debugging - Layout Container Hints?

Tags: magento2, layout, page-layouts

In the admin there are three options for debugging your theme layout:

- Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront
- Enabled Template Path
- Hints for Admin Add Block Names to Hints

When at least the first one is enabled, you get red rectangles highlighting where a template file starts and ends.

These correspond to all places a block class is mentioned in the layout XML file. If the 3rd option is selected you also see the name of the block class.

**Question:**

Is it possible to output the container name(s) wrapping the blocks?

Comment: I was also wondering, but still no answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the following 3rd party module covers your needs:

[H&O Magento 2 Advanced Template Hints module](https://github.com/ho-nl/magento2-Ho_Templatehints)

Apart from the container names, it shows hints for UI Components as well.

Furthermore, it is less messy than the default magento hinting system because it displays the hints in browser's console.